# Много параметров функции + регулярные выражения

Tags: javascript

Создайте функцию "parts", которая принимает несколько параметров. Каждый параметр - это группа предложений.
Эта функция должна извлекать подстроку от знака «:» (двоеточие) до знака «.» (Точка) каждого параметра.
и вернуть массив этих подстрок. Используйте Function Definition Expressions.
Не понимаю, что делаю не так.

```js
const param1 = 'This is the first sentence. This is a sentence with a list of items: cherries, oranges, apples, bananas.';
const param2 = 'This is the second sentence. This is a sentence with a list of items: red, blue, yellow, black.';

let result = function parts(...param) {
  param.match(/:(.*?)\./gmi);

};

parts(param1, param2);
```

Comment: А где function declaration ? И return-а нет. Ну и у массивов нет метода match. И в result у вас функция записана. А parts не существует нигде кроме как внутри самой функции.

Comment: Исправляю, там в задании Function Definition Expressions

Comment: Ну Вы хоть бы текст своего задания изменили, а то выглядит как требование к сообществу :)

Comment: Да никаких требований)
Непонятно мне было, как задание сделать. Сразу две темы новых, а в документации примеров мало :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вашем коде функция `parts` будет видна только внутри этой же функции. Обычно функции написаны как Function Expression анонимны (просто есть переменная, которая ссылается на них).

```
function [name]([param1[, param2[, ..., paramN]]]) {
   statements
}
```

> **name** - The function name. Can be omitted, in which case the function is anonymous. The name is only local to the function body.

```js
const param1 = 'This is the first sentence. This is a sentence with a list of items: cherries, oranges, apples, bananas.';
const param2 = 'This is the second sentence. This is a sentence with a list of items: red, blue, yellow, black.';

const parts = function (...param) {
  return param.map(e => e.match(/:(.*?)\./gmi));
};

console.log(parts(param1, param2));
```

Comment: Спасибо! Да просто в самом задании было условие назвать функцию parts. И мне, если честно, не очень понятно, какое из имен const или function имелось в виду.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, и проанализируйте разницу:

```js
const param1 = 'This is the first sentence. This is a sentence with a list of items: cherries, oranges, apples, bananas.';
const param2 = 'This is the second sentence. This is a sentence with a list of items: red, blue, yellow, black.';

const parts = function (...param) {
  return param.map(str => str.match(/:(.*?)\./)[1]);
};

const result = parts(param1, param2);
console.log(result);
```